# Can we discuss this question please?

Tags: discussion

The question [is this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/107217/8146).

At heart, it has a definite problem (OP wants to create more camaraderie in the team).

I wouldn't describe it as too broad, but happy to hear other thoughts.

If it was any more specific ("Gary only likes talking about hamsters, Jen had a traumatic vision one day and only talks to the ghosts she sees, how can i encourage more camaraderie") then it would be too specific to be of any use to anyone else.

I think it's useful having a "how do i do soft-skills thing" as a workplace issue, especially given that so many questions are about soft-skills here.

Closing it

1. dissuades current users from asking that question
2. creates a culture where new users who ask this kind of question will not be embraced by the community

Finally, some of the comments border on being surprisingly rude, I'm unsure what inspired such invective from the question:

- Find a group of drama queens to work with
- are you just sticking your nose in other people's business

Comment: It was a bad question with worse advice.

Comment: @RichardU what made it a "bad question"?

Comment: I think the rather colorful commentary spelled it out quite nicely.

Comment: This bad question is has also been deleted for self explanatory reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Soft skills questions are not bad *per se*, but they only really work on the site when there is a fairly specific situation and goal that we can address or if it's a specific aspect that they want help with.

The linked question was bad because it was a nebulous request for advice as to how to get his coworkers to share their "emotional" side without any indication of an *actual* impact this lack of "emotional" sharing was having on the work, in fact if anything the OP seemed to be indicating that communication about the *work* was already happening - they just wanted the emotional side because of "synergy" apparently which sounds like a flimsy cover for basically trying to pressure people into sharing personal information to satisfy their own needs or curiosity perhaps.

The OP gave no indication of what his relative position to these other group members is which would make a huge difference to any meaningful answer as to how and what they could do anyway, and ignored a comment asking for clarification on that from Tinkeringbell and to cap it off they were borderline rude in response to Tinkeringbell's answer because it wasn't what they wanted to hear. So it was a **bad** question on here - maybe a variant would gain better traction over on IPS, I honestly don't know.

Comment: Empirical evidence suggests that what would have been bad questions here usually end up in IPS' SNQ, so there is a good chance that question would be a good fit for IPS.